# How to find number of databases in Redis (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, redis

So I am writing a node app that reads from redis, I would like to do a query of some sort that returns the number of databases does anyone know how to do that.

So right now basically what I have is a way to get all keys in a database but I want the level higher, I want to iterate over all databases and then get all keys. This is the code for getting all the keys for the current DB.

```
const client = redis.createClient({host: "127.0.0.1", port: 6379});
client.multi()
    .keys('*', function (err, replies) {
        console.log("MULTI got " + replies.length + " replies");
        let dbs = [replies];
        let dbData = {};
        replies.forEach(function (reply, index) {
            client.get(reply, function (err, data) {
                console.log(reply + " " +data);
            });
        });

    })
    .exec(function (err, replies) { });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Solution 1

As @carebdayrvis mentioned, you can use `INFO` command to get the database info, and parse the info to get the number of databases.

There're two problems with this solution:

1. It only returns the info of databases that are NOT empty. It doesn't show you the total number of databases.
2. If the format of the info text changes, you have to rewrite the parsing code.

> Solution 2

Call `CONFIG GET DATABASES` to get the total number of databases. This result includes both empty and non-empty databases. You can use `SELECT db-index` and `DBSIZE` commands to figure out which databases are NOT empty.

The advantage of this solution is that it's more programmable.

> Other Stuff

By the way, `KEYS` **should NOT** be used in production environment, it might block Redis for a long time. You should consider using `SCAN` command instead.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed both for the databases and the scan command.

Comment: The exact syntax in node is this:
client.config(['get', 'databases'], (err, reply) => {
            numberOfDbs = parseInt(reply[1]);
            client.quit();
            return resolve(numberOfDbs);
        });

It comes back as an array and is the second thing in the array (hence the reply[1])

Answer (score 1):

[This redis command's](https://redis.io/commands/INFO) output includes that information. You should be able to call that from a node client.

Answer (score 1):

> Redis security recommends disabling the CONFIG command so that remote users cannot reconfigure an instance. The RedisHttpSessionConfiguration requires access to this during its initialization. Hosted Redis services, like AWS ElastiCache disable this command by default, with no option to re-enable it.

Ref: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/124

One more reliable alternative is to use the select command and loop until you get an error.