# Redis: List all data structures

Tags: redis

I'm absolutely a newbie using redis.

I need to:

1. list all databases
2. list all data structures

I've connected to redis 4.0.11 server using `redis-cli`.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263381/how-to-find-number-of-databases-in-redis-nodejs) for listing all databases. What do you mean by listing all data structures?

Answer (score 0):

Redis is a key value storage not a database, You can't query or structure the Redis like you do in a database. You can only receive the relevant value from the key that you are passing.

Usually instead of database a key value storage like redis is used to to high performance key value storage and retrieve, if performance of a database is not enough.

Comment: So, am'not I able to store several lists, hashs...?

Comment: you can prefix the key if you want for an example user_user1, (user_<username>) , And you can also use a list of item is a single value if you want something like key -> users, value -> ['user1', 'user2', ..]